# How to reference and modify a std::unique_ptr's underlying value in another function?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I am trying to modify the value within a unique_ptr, but inside another function which doesn't actually own the unique_ptr, as follows:

```
void my_func(Foo* foo) {
  foo->set_bar("a");
} 

int main() {
  auto foo = std::MakeUnique<Foo>();

  my_func(foo.get());

  cout << foo->bar;
}
```

I thought this would work, except I'm met with an error complaining of a deleted constructor. Is there a way to make this pattern work?

Comment: what is a `MakeUnique`? What is a `Foo`? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Inside? That's a pointer. Managed by? That's what the pointer refers to.

Comment: Once I make the required corrections and fill in the blanks I'm not seeing any problems: https://ideone.com/zZwgZv . [mcve] definitely required.

Comment: Unrelated suggestion: If you make `my_func` look more like `void my_func(const std::unique_ptr<Foo> & foo)`, the ownership of `foo` remains clear. Last thing you want is some knucklehead coming along and dropping a `delete foo;` somewhere in there.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are actually using `std::make_unique<Foo>()`.

Since it is an error with construction, this is most likely a problem with the `Foo` type, not with what you are trying to do with it. Although, it could also stem from the `set_bar()` function.

Using `std::make_unique<Foo>()` will attempt to use the default constructor (the one with no arguments). It would appear that your `Foo` type does not have a default constructor. Although, without the implementation of `Foo` at hand, this is just a guess. You need to give `std::make_unique<Foo>()` arguments that correspond to one of the defined constructors of Foo <sup>1</sup>.

Re: What you are trying to do - this seems like it should work. Although, since it is taking a raw pointer, you should consider doing some `nullptr` checks.

<sup>1: If there is at least one constructor defined, where one is not the default constructor, *the default constructor is deleted*.</sup>